# SQL Server setting and db to Jetbrains DataGrid

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

How do I migrate my SQL Server settings and active databases to Jetbrains DataGrid?

I followed the steps on their website, but the one I have is not jtMssql or SQL Server with user login, but Windows authentication. If I need to add any setup configuration file, where do I get it?